# TableView not visible on execution

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This question has been asked here quite a few times but they don't seem to solve my issue.

I am running Swift 4, I have a TableView wired to view controller.

[image: datasource and Delegate wired to the view]

The following is my code in ViewController.Swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let dailyTasks = ["Check all windows","Check all doors", "Check temparature of freezer", "check mailbox at end of the lane", "Empty trash containers",
                      "if freezing then check water pipes outside"]

    let weeklyTasks = ["check inside all unoccupied cabins", "Run all faucets for 30 seconds", "Walk the perimeter of property", "Arrange for dumpster pickup"]

    let twoWeektasks = ["Run test on security alarm", "Check all motion detectors", "Check smoke alarms"]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return dailyTasks.count
        case 1 :
            return weeklyTasks.count
        case 2 :
            return twoWeektasks.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell ()

        var currenTask: String
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
               currenTask =    dailyTasks[indexPath.row]

        case 1: currenTask  = weeklyTasks [indexPath.row]

        case 2: currenTask  = twoWeektasks[indexPath.row]

        default:
             currenTask  = ""

        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = currenTask
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "dailyTasks"
        case 1:
            return "weeklyTasks"
        case 2:
            return "twoWeektasks"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         print ("You selected row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")
    }
}
```

However when I run the program I see an empty view. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Did you set the table's `dataSource` to be the view controller and constraint the table to be in a visible place in storyboard?

Comment: I copied your code into a test app and it's working fine.  The only thing I can think of is perhaps you don't have the constraints on the table view setup correctly.

Comment: @Miket25 can you let me know how I can set dataSource to view controller? My understanding was that setting it in UI properties like I did in the attached image is enough.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I did a "resolve auto layout issues" in editor to take care of issues with setting up tableview but it doesn't seem to help the case.

Comment: @JeremyKnothing Yes, that's correct. I didn't notice you did it through Storyboard.

Comment: You can try creating an IBOutlet of the UITableView and then do something like `tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1`.  That will put a border around the table view itself and thus eliminate any problem with positioning vs cell display.  If you can post the project or a repository of it I can take a look.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I have uploaded the project here. Thanks. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bhng6d757fk68o/TableView3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Where?  Did you miss the link out?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth sorry my bad, https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bhng6d757fk68o/TableView3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Adding back a new UITableView and setting the constraints to fit the screen fixed it. Seemed to be a constraint issue the whole time 

Comment: First it didn't compile because of this line `self.tableView.dataSource = self` in viewDidLoad but you can just comment that out.  Second the reason you are not seeing anything is because you have added the table view to your 'LaunchScreen' storyboard when it should have been done in your 'Main' storyboard.  Just move the table view into the 'Main' storyboard and setup the data source and delegate again and it should all work.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Oh wow, good eye. Didn't even think to check there . I though the OP just removed the tableView for the upload.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth  wew, thanks. I didn't check where I was storyboarding.

Comment: No problem the simple mistakes are often the hardest to spot.